# Scatter matrix using pandas does not reset any graph

Tags: python, pixel, scatterplot

I would like to find the statistical correlation between all the pixels of an image in relation to the bands. In my case 7.

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import gdal_array
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
%matplotlib inline

dataset = gdal.Open( "C:\Mosaico.tif") 
image_datatype = dataset.GetRasterBand(1).DataType
image = np.zeros((dataset.RasterYSize, dataset.RasterXSize, dataset.RasterCount),
                  dtype=gdal_array.GDALTypeCodeToNumericTypeCode(image_datatype))   

for b in range(dataset.RasterCount):
    band = dataset.GetRasterBand(b + 1)
    image[:, :, b] = band.ReadAsArray()

df=pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(image))

scatter_matrix(df,figsize = (10,10), diagonal = 'hist')
```

Comment: Can you expand a bit more “doesn’t work”part?

Comment: I changed my code because I don't think it was right, I think I'll let him read the pandas in the image array, but I noticed that with `seaborn.scatterplot` it also causes me problems

Comment: Can you please review your code before posting here? It looks like half of it is coming from somewhere else. Where did you define `img`, where do you use `srcband` and `img_array`, etc.?

Comment: I'm sorry, and that in a fury of doing tests I copied the code without looking at it properly, is driving me crazy

Comment: I use that loop code to make sure because I noticed that otherwise the image array was represented by null values, with this I think I have solved that problem.